# How to get a specific string from a variable using Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a code which returns an access token string.

```
#!/bin/bash
token=$(curl --globoff -X POST "https://example.com/token" -F 'grant_type=client_credentials' -F 'client_id=d86fc9b690963b8dda602bd26f33454r457e9024a4ecccf4c3bbf66ffcbc241b' -F 'client_code'='ff148c56118728b62c9f2ew3e4r009a7a1c645276b70611fa32fa055b9944934')
echo "$token" > Token.txt
```

The output given by this command is :

```
{
    "access_token": "5048e7d38e73b4a809a4fcb219b63ae34f34f43f83d6663ffd777203afb5654ab",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 7200
}
```

ie. the variable `token` contains the above result. My question is how to get the access token `5048e7d38e73b4a809a4fcb219b63ae34f34f43f83d6663ffd777203afb5654ab` alone from this and save to another variable.

Comment: Download and install `JSON` parser utility [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/), **if not possible**, this is a workaround using `awk`:

```
access_token=$(curl --globoff -X POST "https://example.com/token" \
                    -F 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
                    -F 'client_id=d86fc9b690963b8dda602bd26f33454r457e9024a4ecccf4c3bbf66ffcbc241b' \
                    -F 'client_code'='ff148c56118728b62c9f2ew3e4r009a7a1c645276b70611fa32fa055b9944934'|\
                    awk -F\" '/access_token/{print $4}')
```

---

The way to do this in `jq` would be to do

```
access_token=$(curl --globoff -X POST "https://example.com/token" \
                    -F 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
                    -F 'client_id=d86fc9b690963b8dda602bd26f33454r457e9024a4ecccf4c3bbf66ffcbc241b' \
                    -F 'client_code'='ff148c56118728b62c9f2ew3e4r009a7a1c645276b70611fa32fa055b9944934'|\
                    jq -r '.access_token' )
```

Comment: Why would you want to parse `JSON` using `Awk`? I think it would be wise to recommend best practices than suggesgting short-cuts

Comment: Well it's a pretty simple JSON @Inian , of course `jq`is a very nice tool, but   you have to take in consideration that some peolple can't install things in the system.

Comment: Fair point, but it would be good to check with OP on that and suggest if they could use other tools

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in bash to get and use the token ...

```
access_tok=$(curl -s -X POST -d "client_id=$(< "$LOGON_HOME/client_id" )&client_secret=$(< "$LOGON_HOME/client_secret")&grant_type=client_credentials" "${TOKEN_URL}" )
access_tok=${access_tok#*access_token\":\"}
access_tok=${access_tok%%\"*}
```

and later

```
curl -l -s -O -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_tok}" "${FILE_URL}"
```